# Intercepting Async Proxy Service exceptions for GWT RPC

Tags: gwt, exception, gwt-rpc

My app has many RPC calls, and they all have a .onFailure(Throwable caught) method. I have a class shared between the client and the server code NotLoggedInException. This is thrown by the server, if the user doesn't have the relevant permissions based on sessions/cookies/permissions etc.

Ideally I would like to handle this exception in one place BEFORE others are passed to the .onFailure() code, given how ubiquitous this handling is and needs to be for security. There is a GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler() but this appears to get called after the handling which isn't ideal (in case an .onFailure accidentally consumes too much).

Does anybody have an elegant solution to this? An ugly solution is to wrap the deferred binded .create() proxy in the same aggregated class implementing the async interface.

Sidenote: The server was issuing a redirect before, but I don't like this paradigm, and would prefer it to be handled by the eventbus of the app.

Update: ugly answer referred to above

`public abstract class CustomAsyncCallback implements AsyncCallback{`

```
@Override
public CustomAsyncCallback(AsyncCallback<T> callback)
{
    this.wrap = callback ;
}

AsyncCallback<T> wrap ;


@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    if (!handleException())
{
    wrap.onFailure(caught) ;
}
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(T t) {
    wrap.onSuccess(t) ;
}
```

}

public class WrapDeferredBinding implements RpcInterfaceAsync
{
        RpcInterfaceAsync service = GWT.create(RpcInterface.class);

```
public void method1(int arg1, AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback)
{
    service.method1(arg1, new CustomAsyncCallback<Boolean>(callback)) ;
}

public void method2 ....
public void method3 ....
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to wrap every `AsynCallback<T>` that is passed to any `RemoteService` you need to override `RemoteServiceProxy#doCreateRequestCallback()` because every `AsynCallback<T>` is handed in here before an RPC call happens.

#### Here are the steps to do so:

To begin you need to define your own Proxy Generator to step in every time a `RemoteService` proxy gets generated. Start by extending `ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator` and overriding `#createProxyCreator()`.

```java
/**
 * This Generator extends the default GWT {@link ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator} and replaces it in the
 * co.company.MyModule GWT module for all types that are assignable to
 * {@link com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService}. Instead of the default GWT {@link ProxyCreator} it provides the
 * {@link MyProxyCreator}.
 */
public class MyServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator extends ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator {
    @Override
    protected ProxyCreator createProxyCreator(JClassType remoteService) {
        return new MyProxyCreator(remoteService);
    }
}
```

In your `MyModule.gwt.xml` make use of deferred binding to instruct GWT to compile using your Proxy Generator whenever it generates something of the type `RemoteService`:

```xml
<generate-with 
   class="com.company.ourapp.rebind.rpc.MyServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService"/>
</generate-with>
```

Extend `ProxyCreator` and override `#getProxySupertype()`. Use it in `MyServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator#createProxyCreator()` so that you can define the base class for all the generated `RemoteServiceProxies`.

```java
/**
 * This proxy creator extends the default GWT {@link ProxyCreator} and replaces {@link RemoteServiceProxy} as base class
 * of proxies with {@link MyRemoteServiceProxy}.
 */
public class MyProxyCreator extends ProxyCreator {
    public MyProxyCreator(JClassType serviceIntf) {
        super(serviceIntf);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends RemoteServiceProxy> getProxySupertype() {
        return MyRemoteServiceProxy.class;
    }
}
```

Make sure both your `MyProxyCreator` and your `MyServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator` are located in a package that will not get cross-compiled by GWT into javascript. Otherwise you will see an error like this:

```
[ERROR] Line XX: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ProxyCreator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

You are now ready to extend `RemoteServiceProxy` and override `#doCreateRequestCallback()`! Here you can do anything you like and apply it to every callback that goes to your server. Make sure that you add this class, and any other class you use here, in my case `AsyncCallbackProxy`, to your client package to be cross-compiled.

```java
/**
 * The remote service proxy extends default GWT {@link RemoteServiceProxy} and proxies the {@link AsyncCallback} with
 * the {@link AsyncCallbackProxy}.
 */
public class MyRemoteServiceProxy extends RemoteServiceProxy {
    public MyRemoteServiceProxy(String moduleBaseURL, String remoteServiceRelativePath, String serializationPolicyName,
                                 Serializer serializer) {
        super(moduleBaseURL, remoteServiceRelativePath, serializationPolicyName, serializer);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RequestCallback doCreateRequestCallback(RequestCallbackAdapter.ResponseReader responseReader,
                                                          String methodName, RpcStatsContext statsContext,
                                                          AsyncCallback<T> callback) {
        return super.doCreateRequestCallback(responseReader, methodName, statsContext, new AsyncCallbackProxy<T>(callback));
    }
}
```

Now, your `AsyncCallbackProxy` can look something like this:

```java
public class AsyncCallbackProxy<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
    private AsyncCallback<T> delegate;

    public AsyncCallbackProxy(AsyncCallback<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        GWT.log("AsyncCallbackProxy#onFailure() : " + caught.getMessage(), caught);

        if (caught instanceof NotLoggedInException) {
            // Handle it here
        }

        delegate.onFailure(proxy);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSuccess(T result) {
        delegate.onSuccess(result);
    }
}
```

---

References:

- [DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)
- [An example applied to performance tracking](http://josephmarques.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/performance-monitoring-using-gwt/)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. An example of how to use generators for this purpose was what I think was needed to answer this question. Many thanx.

Comment: not working for me. I dont get any errors but the calls are not intercepted :/

Comment: i gwt compiled the project again, and now is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `AsyncCallback` class with an abstract class:

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T>{

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        GWT.log(caught.getMessage());
        handleException();

        this.customOnFailure(yourDesireParam);
    }

    /**
     * this method is optional
     */
    public abstract void customOnFailure(Param yourDesireParam);
}
```

And then send a `CustomAsyncCallback` object to your RPC asynch methods.

Comment: Thanx for that. In the question I did refer to wrapping the deferred binding class. It would look similar to your approach & would need a CustomAsyncCallback, but it would be transparent for all the cases using AsyncCallback (see above). Your approach is more efficient as you don't need to create dummy wrapper instances, but it requires code changes everywhere and if my team accidentally Override onFailure it would eclipse CustomAsyncCallback (although could be made final). Ideally, I would want alterations to com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ProxyCreator, but it looks hairy if unfamiliar. :-)